# Python: Automatically Generate Google Form

Tags: python, google-forms

I'd like to be able to generate and publish a google form using python code. Is this possible?

Comment: [Yes it is possible](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

Comment: [Yes it is](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below link will give you an idea:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/32xd4s/how_can_i_use_python_to_submit_a_google_form_or/